# Error NU1101: Unable to find package ProjectABC.Core.Services. No packages exist with this id in source(s)

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to implement CI/CD on Azure DevOps for my Asp.net Core project.

Project having Nuget packages from three different sources:

[image]

MSBUild in Azure Pipeline is going to find nuget packages in Offline Packages or Nuget.org only but not going to find external source which i am also using:
http://dev-abc-api-nugetserver-wi.azurewebsites.net/nuget/

I have tried below code in Azure Pipeline Build but that didn't work

```
/p:RestoreAdditionalSources="http://dev-abc-api-nugetserver-wi.azurewebsites.net/nuget/"  /t:Rebuild
```

But still receiving same error:

> Error NU1101: Unable to find package abc.Core.Services. No packages
>   exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
>   Packages, nuget.org

My build pipeline:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: added snapshot of pipeline

Comment: try to add a NuGet restore task and specify your nuget.config (in the nuget.config put your private repo)

Comment: this is asp.Net CORE project so doesn't have nuget.config

Comment: you can create a nuget.config and commit/check in to your solution, then try to run `dotnet restore` before your build.

Comment: Tried with creating nuget.config... gives error Valid file names are 'packages.config' or 'packages.*.config'

Comment: Tried with renaming it to packages.config... Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.)
Packages failed to restore

Comment: can you share your dotent restore task...?

Comment: can you give me your skype id ??(Unknown command: 'dotnet')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193239/discussion-between-shayki-abramczyk-and-sagar-modi).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create `nuget.config` file (and commit/check in to your project), in the file you need specify your NuGet sources (include your external source).

In your build pipeline add .Net core task with the `restore` command, specify your `.csproj` file and check the "Feeds in my NuGet config", create a NuGet endpoint with username & password for your external nuget repo.

[image]

After this task all your packages should be downloaded and the build should be run successfully.